# ¿Qué hace exactamente la ordenación por "más frecuente"?

Tags: soporte, preguntas, búsqueda

Al filtrar preguntas hay una opción de ordenación "Más frecuente":

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿En qué consiste exactamente ese tipo de ordenación?

Comment: supongo que las que visitas mas frecuentemente..o las mas visitadas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se refiere a las preguntas que tienen más enlaces hacia ellas.

Referencia: [respuesta del eterno Shog9](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344319/1983854), [CM echado en contra de cualquier lógica y para disgusto de la comunidad](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342059/209901), a la pregunta *What does the Frequent tab mean?* en Meta.SO.